# Promesas-Javascript-Undefined

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, function, promesas

Hola No entiendo porque mi código de javascript me da undefined, estoy usando un array de objetos en la primera parte.

Luego hago mis funciones para luego más tarde invocarlas, retornando en cada una promise pero no entiendo en qué estoy fallando ya que con el `catch` se imprime en consola de maravilla pero con `then` me sale `undefined`.

Código:

```javascript
const users = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Cristian"
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Perlita"
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Ramon"
}];

const email = [
    {
        id: 1,
        email: "cristianjosehcls@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        email: "cristikajose@gmail.com"
    }];

const getUser = (id) => {
    const usuarios = users.find(usaurio => usaurio.id == id);
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!usuarios) { reject(`no existe el id de users con parametro ${id}`) } else { resolve(console.log(usuarios)) }
    })
    return promise
}
const getEmail = (user) => {
    const correos = email.find(mensajes => mensajes.id == user)
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!correos) { reject(`no existe un id de correo comparativo a ${user} `) } else {
            resolve({
                id: users.id,
                name: users.name,
                email: email.email
            })
        }
    })
    return promise
}

getUser(1).then(positive => getEmail(positive))
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problema

El problema está en la función `getUser` ya que la misma no devuelve ningún valor, es decir, devuelve `undefined`:

```js
const getUser = (id) => {
    const usuarios = users.find(usaurio => usaurio.id == id);
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!usuarios) { 
          reject(`no existe el id de users con parametro ${id}`)
        } else { 
          resolve(console.log(usuarios))} // A resolve deberías pasarle un valor, en este caso la variable "usuarios",
          //lo que le estas pasando a resolve es lo que devuelve la función console.log(), que es undefined 
    })
    return promise
}
```

### Solución

La solución es devolver el objeto "usuario":

NOTAS: Además de devolver el objeto `usuario` también hice otras correcciones necesarias, mas que nada nombre de variables. Están comentadas en el código.

```js
const users = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Cristian"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Perlita"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Ramon"
  }];
const email = [
    {
        id: 1,
        email: "cristianjosehcls@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        email: "cristikajose@gmail.com"
    }];

const getUser = (id) => {
    const usuarios = users.find(usaurio => usaurio.id == id);
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!usuarios) { 
            reject(`no existe el id de users con parametro ${id}`) 
          } else { 
            resolve(usuarios) //Acá devolvemos el objeto
          }
    })
    return promise
}
const getEmail = (user) => {
    const correos = email.find(mensajes => mensajes.id == user.id)
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!correos) { 
          reject(`no existe un id de correo comparativo a ${user.name} `)
          } else {
            resolve({
                id: user.id, // Usamos "user" no "users"
                name: user.name, //idem
                email: correos.email // usamos "correos" no "email"
            })
        }
    })
    return promise
}

getUser(1).then(positive => getEmail(positive))
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

getUser(3).then(positive => getEmail(positive))
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

---

Si ejecutas el siguiente fragmento de código, notaras que el valor de la variable es `undefined`.

Puedes probar abriendo la consola del navegador F12 y escribir `console.log("algo")` y notaras que además de que se loguee el mensaje, la siguiente línea mostrará `undefined` ya que la función `console.log()` no devuelve ningún valor.

```js
let undefinedVariable = console.log("");

console.log("Valor -> ", undefinedVariable);
```

Comment: Excelente amigo me sirvió me podrías explicar el porque de las modificaciones que hiciste en este fragmento de código y el porque de ello, realmente muy interesado en comprenderlo:  resolve({
                id: user.id, // Usamos "user" no "users"
                name: user.name, //idem
                email: correos.email // usamos "correos" no "email"
            })
        }
    })
    return promise

Comment: @CristianÁlvarez Las correcciones son porque los nombres de las variables estaban mal. si la respuesta solucionó tu problema considera marcarla como respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar algo así, el resolve de la primer promesa no está retornando nada, por lo que al llamarla daba undefined, por otro lado tenías algunos problemas de acceso a los datos dentro de arrays y objetos, espero te sirva, creo que ahí estaría funcionando, marqué con //modificado donde hice cambios.

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Cristian",
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Perlita" },
  { id: 3, name: "Ramon" },
];

const email = [
  { id: 1, email: "cristianjosehcls@gmail.com" },
  { id: 2, email: "cristikajose@gmail.com" },
];

const getUser = (id) => {
  const usuarios = users.find((usaurio) => usaurio.id == id);
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!usuarios) {
      reject(`no existe el id de users con parametro ${id}`);
    } else {
      resolve(usuarios); // modificado
    }
  });
  return promise;
};

const getEmail = (user) => {
  const correos = email.find((mensajes) => mensajes.id == user.id); // modificado
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!correos) {
      reject(`no existe un id de correo comparativo a ${user.id} `); // modificado
    } else {
      resolve({ id: user.id, name: user.name, email: correos.email }); // modificado
    }
  });
  return promise;
};

getUser(1)
  .then((positive) => getEmail(positive))
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: La respuesta es básicamente la misma que la de arriba, pero con menos explicaciones.

Comment: No me muestra la hora de mi respuesta, pero seguramente la respondimos al mismo tiempo o muy cerca, yo estaba refrescando las preguntas, quizás tardé un poco más o menos en armar la respuesta, no lo se, solo dediqué un tiempo a armarlo y lo mandé esperando sea útil.